# Not able to use Serverless VPC Access for Cloud Run and Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-run, vpc

I have a Cloud Run service and a Compute Engine VM instance, both are in europe-north1 region.
I would like to connect Cloud Run to Compute Engine VM Instance's internal IP address. For that I tried to create a 'Serverless VPC Access'. When I see the supported regions, there are europe-west[1-3] but not europe-north... And the documentation says that:

> In the Region field, select a region for your connector. This must match the region of your serverless service

Does this mean that I cannot use Serverless VPC Access if my services are in europe-north1?

Nevertheless, I created the VPC in europe-west3, thinking that it is the closest one, with suggested IP range: 10.8.0.0/28. However, when I go to CloudRun>service>Edit&Deploy New Revision>Connections tab, I don't get the VPC Connector listed in dropdown box. It has already been 30 mins that I created the connector. Does it take more time to appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Europe-north1 isn't a [supported region for serverless vpc connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#supported_regions).

If you created a serverless VPC access in europe-west3, it is immediately available for Cloud RUn (or other services). If you don't see it, I think it's because your Cloud Run service isn't in the same region. Only the compliant serverless VPC connectors are shown (and available).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it mean that Cloud Run cannot talk to a VM with internal IP if they both are not in the same supported regions? Is there an alternative besides serverless VPC? This looks like a big constraint to me...

Comment: I think that Serverless VPC connector is planned to be deployed in all region where Cloud Run and Cloud Functions are available. It's a matter of weeks or months... Up to that, you haven't alternative, except reaching a public IP.

Comment: Does this help?